# Variable derived from React redux useSelector in useCallback dependency array causes infinite re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a list `topics` derived from `useSelector` and I use it in one of my callback function `updateXXX` and add it into the `useCallback` array of dependencies, unfortunately it causes infinite rendering. Can someone give me some suggestions? How am I supposed to solve the issue?

```
const topics = useSelector(...);

const updateXXX = useCallback(() => {
    const filteredTopics = topics.filter(...);
}, [topics]);
```

AFAIK, for `useState()`

> React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.

My question is do we need to add the return value `topics` from `useSelector()` into any dependencies array?

I observed that the infinite rendering happens only when `topics` is an empty list `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You are using array as dependency. dependency array only takes primitive types. In your case, you can use `[topics.length]`. When there is a change in number of elements in the array, useEffect will execute callback function.

Comment: Actually that's not true and your answer doesn't handle case when you have some changes to array, but it's length doesn't change. For example you can delete one element and add one, and that useCallback wouldn't be called. 
Dependency array looks for provided values, and in case if you provide an object, it will look at that object's link to memory, so when you will get new array after state update, your callback will be called again.

Comment: The above is true, _but_ the answer does state that the hook will re-run when "there is a change in number of elements". So both the answer and the above comment are valid. One should be aware of this behaviour when using `arrayVariable.length`, to understand _why_ a hook has or hasn't run as an Array mutates